# Rails + Devise: How can I check if a user is remembered when signing in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, remember-me

How can I find out if a user who is signing in was remembered through an older session.

I found this answer: [Rails/Devise: execute action after automatic login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897224/rails-devise-execute-action-after-automatic-login)
and it says that the after_remembered method gets called after a user was remembered. I tried it out and put it in my model but it doesn't get called.
I even put a binding.pry before this line https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/rememberable.rb#L30
but the whole authenticate! method doesn't even get called when signing in.

I hope someone can help

Comment: There is a column that comes with devise that is called user_sign_in_count. You could use that in the after_sign_in method with a conditional

Comment: The only method I found that resembles the one you mentioned is https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L217 and I don't think that would help me because I would have to check for changes on the sign_in_count. If the user is remembered, the count doesn't change. I mean I could maybe save the count before the controller action and compare it after it finished, but that's really hacky. I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: When you say user, you are speaking of an already registered one?

Comment: yes a registered user who automatically gets signed in through the "remember me" function

Comment: I might have found a solution... I can probably create an after_update callback in the model and check if the current_sign_in_at field changed. If not then the user was remembered and I can set an attr_accessor. I will try it out tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my previous idea with creating an after_update callback didn't work since it wouldn't get updated on an remembered session.

What I ended up doing isn't really pretty, but I also didn't want to monkeypatch warden.

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  around_action :check_remembered, only: :create

  def create
    super
  end

  private
  def check_remembered
    # find the user based on the email in the login params. 
    # You can't use current_user here because once you call it, 
    # it will update the user before the action even ran (no idea why)
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
    yield
    if user && user.sign_in_count != current_user.sign_in_count
      # user was not remembered
    end
  end
 end
```

For email only sign ins this is enough. If you are using omniauth sign ins then you have to block every omniauth sign in in the check_remembered function by checking if `params[:user][:email]` is present. Those will have to be handled in your omniauth controller.